# Грубая ли ошибка

Tags: пунктуация

[Бревенчатая дача моя была не совсем достроена — неконопаченые стены, неструганые полы, печи без
заслонок, мебели почти никакой.]

Мне исправили "—" на  ":", считается ли это за грубую ошибку?

Comment: Здесь не то что не грубая ошибка, а вообще нет ошибки.Современные правила пунктуации допускают использовать тире вместо двоеточия в этом случае. .

Comment: Но в ЕГЭ это не допускается, ошибка.

Comment: Я тоже не вижу здесь ошибки: возможна интонация, отличная от случая простого перечисления. Тире позволяет отнестись к перечисляемому как к эмоционально выделеному пояснению причины того, почему автор считает дачу недостроенной - мол, там и сям можно найти недоделки. Тире может и замещать подразумеваемое "куда ни глянь" - одно не готово, другое забыто и т. д.

Comment: А-а, если это ЕГЭ, то тогда, конечно, ошибка.

Answer (score 4):

Нет, это негрубая ошибка - замена одного знака другим.

К негрубым относятся:

1) Большая буква в составных наименованиях и в собственных именах нерусского происхождения;

2) трудные случаи различения "не" и "ни" (никто иной, как... – не кто иной, как ...);.

3) слитное и раздельное правописание предлогов с наречиями, не регулируемое правилами;

4) пропуск одного из сочетающихся знаков;

5) замена одного знака другим;

6) ошибки в исключениях из правил.

Comment: Людмила, а почему Вы считаете, что постановка тире в этом предложении -- ошибка (пусть и негрубая)?

Comment: Потому что это школа, а в школьных правилах строго ставится двоеточие, если  вторая часть раскрывает или дополняет смысл того, о чём говорится в первой. Можно вставить " а именно"  . Бревенчатая дача моя была не совсем достроена (а именно в чём это выражалось?) :  (там были) неконопаченые стены, неструганые полы, печи без заслонок, мебели почти никакой.]

Comment: Людмила, помните, мы здесь обсуждали мой вопрос о постановки двоеточия вместо тире в ЕГЭ?Я выполнял тесты на Грамма.ру, и поставил тире вместо двоеточия. Я даже писал им. Остановились на том ( и там и здесь), что в ЕГЭ, все же надо следовать строгим правилам.

Comment: Вот именно. И это вопрос о школьном задании. Нужно следовать правилам, показать их знания.